# R not accepting xpath query

Tags: xml, r, xpath, web-scraping

Hi I am using the XML package in R to scrape html pages. The page of interest is http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/225903367?report=fasta and on that page there is a sequence of which when inspecting the element in chrome, the xpath is

```
//*[@id="gi_225903367_141"]
```

however when I try to pull this using:

```
xpathSApply(htmlParse(fasta.url.content),"//*[@id="viewercontent1"]/pre")
Error: unexpected symbol in "xpathSApply(htmlParse(fasta.url.content),"//*[@id="viewercontent1"
```

I get the above error.

Is the XML package being fussy with the xpath?

here is the query using the xpath Mathius has provided

```
xpathSApply(htmlParse(fasta.url.content),"//span[contains(@id,'gi_225903367_1')]")
list()
attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

where I get an empty list. I don't doubt that that xpath is incorrect, but I wonder if this is R related.

Comment: try changing the inner double quotes to single quotes. as `//*[@id='viewercontent1']/pre`

Comment: this seems to work, however receiving an empty list...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what element you're after. Is it `//*[@id="gi_225903367_141"]` or `//*[@id="viewercontent1"]/pre` or `//*[@id="viewercontent1]"`?

Comment: it's the sequence starting with MYS

Comment: Well, and what is `MYS`? Please simply answer my question, what HTML element are you looking for?

Comment: <span class = "ffline"

Comment: Again you are introducing something entirely different. You never mentioned `span[@class = 'ffline']` before. How is that related to `*[@id='viewercontent1']` or `*[@id="gi_225903367_141"]` or even the mysterious `MYS`?

Comment: I am having difficulty explaining the element I need purely through xpath. If you go to this URL http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/225903367?report=fasta you will see a sequence of letters starting with "MYS" and it's that sequence that I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the page is created dynamically using javascript, and the sequence is not visible in the rendering returned to R.

The CRAN package "rentrez" provides an interface to [eutils](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25501/), which is the programmatic way to query Entrez

```
library(rentrez)
entrez_fetch(db="protein", id="225903367", rettype="fasta")
```

Comment: you have saved my life! thank you so much! also thank you for explaining why the sequence wasn't in page source - I figured it out a few hours back but this answer will help anyone to understand why they can't just simply webscrape the html/xml.

Answer (score 1):

This gets the list, although I don't know if it's 100% correct as I don't work with fasta files.  It seems like `lapply(dat, cat)` might need to be called on the `dat` result below.

```
> library(RCurl)
> library(XML)
> url <- getURL("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/225903367?report=fasta")
> dat <- readHTMLList(url)
> length(dat)
# [1] 39
> object.size(dat)
# 42704 bytes
```

The whole list is not very big, so I'd recommend bringing the whole list into R.  Then you have all the relevant data, and you don't have to spend the whole day trying to regex an html document.  It looks like the unexpected symbol might be triggered because you wrote `//*`, and that `*` needs escape characters on it, possibly `//[*]`.

**Edit** that error you got was due to double quotation marks inside other double quotation marks.  In R that should be quoted `"//*[@id='viewercontent1']/pre"`

Yes, `XML` can be fussy, but it's generally because (1) it's the internet, and (2) the parser expects certain things to be in the html code and sometimes it's not.  My professor wrote both `RCurl` and `XML` and he recommends going to `RCurl::getURL` when for the xml document when `XML::readHTMLTable` or any of the other `read*` functions have trouble.

These issues you're having with the output are not strange.  They are an empty result, which is as expected from the functions that assign attributes.

Answer (score 0):

> If you go to this URL ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/225903367?report=fasta
>   you will see a sequence of letters starting with "MYS" and it's that
>   sequence that I need.

Finally I think I understood what you need. The content you are looking for is in the following `span`:

```
<span id="gi_225903367_1" class="ff_line">
    MYSFNTLRLYLWETIVFFSLAASKEAEAARSAPKPMSPSDFLDKLMGRTS…
</span>
```

You find it with an XPath expression like:

```
"//span[@id = 'gi_225903367_1']"
```

Note: This is the correct expression to retrieve a `span` element with the `id` attribute value "gi_225903367_1". I cannot comment on whether you are applying XPath correctly in your R code.

Comment: thanks for your patience Mathius. It must be something I am doing in R

Comment: @brucezepplin Why? What result or error message do you get with the expression above?

Comment: I just get an empty list using the xpath you have provided. I have detailed this in my updated question. The xpath looks correct as you say.

Comment: I think the problem is that if you veiw the page source, the element I am looking for is nowhere to be found in the html content of the url. this to me is strange as the element (xpath you have provided) DOES exist when you right click on the sequence and inspect the element itself. Yet this is not reflected in the page source

Comment: yes - the text on the page "MYS" is being called by a program called "EntrezSystem2.PEntrez.Protein.Sequence_ResultsPanel.SequenceViewer.Sequence_ViewerReport.dopt". this is why I cannot scrape the sequence from the page.

Answer (score 0):

@brucezepplin, I feel your frustration.  @Mathias Muller, I worked with what you wrote and ran the following:

```
test <- "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/225903367?report=fasta" 
doc <- htmlTreeParse(test, asText = TRUE, useInternalNodes = TRUE) 
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'viewercontent1']", xmlValue)
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'viewercontent1']//span[@id = 'gi_225903367_1']", xmlValue)
xpathSApply(doc, "//div[@id = 'viewercontent1']/gi/span", xmlValue))
```

First, when I looked at "doc" it only showed a couple of header lines, not the full page.

But the first xpath returned `list()`, so at least it was functioning.  The next two returned `NUL`L.  There is a `<pre>` before the desired span nodes as well as a >gi.

In short, this is not an answer but perhaps will make it easier for someone else to provide a solution.