# Can't access specific content in html page with rvest and selectorGadget

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to **scrape** a ncbi website (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/29436380) to obtain information of a protein. I need to access the gene_synonyms and GeneID fields. I have tried to find the relevant nodes with the selectorGadget addon in chrome and with the code inspector in ff. I have tried this code:

```
require("dplyr")
require("rvest")
require("stringr")
GIwebPage <- read_html("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/29436380")
TestHTML <- GIwebPage %>% html_node("div.grid , div#maincontent.col.nine_col , div.sequence , pre.genebank , .feature") %>% html_text(trim = TRUE)
```

Then I try to find the relevant text but it is simply not there.

```
str_extract_all(TestHTML, pattern = "(synonym).{30}")
 [[1]]
 character(0)

str_extract_all(TestHTML, pattern = "(GeneID:).{30}")
 [[1]]
 character(0)
```

All I seem to be accessing is some of the text content of the column on the right.

```
str_extract_all(TestHTML, pattern = "(protein).{30}")
 [[1]]
 [1] "protein codes including ambiguities a"
 [2] "protein sequence for myosin-9  (NP_00"
 [3] "protein should not be confused with t"
 [4] "protein, partial [Homo sapiens]gi|294"
 [5] "protein codes including ambiguities a"
```

I have tried so many combinations of nodes selections with html_node() that I don't know anymore what to try. Is this content buried in some structure I can't see? or I'm just not skilled enough to realize the node to select?

Thanks a lot,
José.

Comment: The page is dynamically loading the information.  The information you are looking for is actually stored here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id=29436380&db=protein&report=genpept&conwithfeat=on&withparts=on&show-cdd=on&retmode=html&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000.  You can find this link by using the developer tools from your browser.

Comment: Awesome Dave2e!! Thanks a lot. In fact the page is "static" enough so I can use it in a function to scrape information from several genes. One question though, how did you find that address? I can't seem to find it!!

Comment: Dave2e, I can't mark a comment as an answer but it is for me. Should I leave it as it is??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is dynamically loading the information. The underlying information is store at another location.
Using the developer tools from your bowser, look for the link:

[image]

The information you are looking for is store at the "viewer.fcgi", right click to copy the link.

See similar question/answers: [R not accepting xpath query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603894/r-not-accepting-xpath-query)